# Properly use a matrix double[,] in c#

Tags: c#, matrix

Im trying to pass as parameter this matrix:

```
double[,] array2 = new double[4, 5] 
{
    { 45, -6, 8, -3, 48 },
    { 0, -56.733333, 3.6444444, -6.8666667, 26.8666667 },
    { 0, 0, 78.17111712, -15.2432, -133.378378},
    { 0, 0, 0, 94.190193, 319.457667}
};
```

But when I try to use it in the other function i get problems with out of range, I dont know what I'm doing wrong since I'm using the same range that I specified when I created the objetc double[,] Im using the next code:

For passing the matrix:

```
Example1 a = new Example1();
a.function(array2,4,5);
```

Using the function:

```
public double[] function(double[,] nn, int n, int m)
{
    double[,] ma = new double[n, m];
    ma = nn;
    double[] x = new double[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    x[n] = ma[n, m] / ma[n, n];
    return x;
}
```

Im getting the error when I try to use ma[n,m] / ma[n,n] And I dont know why is happenig cause ma[n,m] it happens to exist and ma[n,n] happens to exist to.

Comment: There’s no point in allocating memory and then assigning the given array to the variable. It doesn’t make a copy.

Comment: You are trying to dividing by zero!

Comment: You are passing in the number of elements in each dimension (4 and 5) to the function, not the upper bounds. Arrays are `0` based, so the upper bound is `number of elements - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, read the documentation

[Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

> **Array Overview**
>
> - An array has the following properties:
> - An array can be Single-Dimensional, Multidimensional or Jagged.
> - The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are established when the array instance is created. These values can't be
>     changed during the lifetime of the instance.
> - The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null.
> - A jagged array is an array of arrays, and therefore its elements are reference types and are initialized to null.
> - **Arrays are zero indexed**: an array with `n` elements is indexed from `0` to `n-1`.
> - Array elements can be of any type, including an array type.
> - Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. Since this type implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, you
>     can use foreach iteration on all arrays in C#.

---

**Some further reading**

- [Multidimensional Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)
- [Zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)
- [Why are zero-based arrays the norm?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the matrix does not recognize double [4,5] cause when declarated goes from [0..3] taking 4 spaces and the [4,#] will take 5 spaces.

Comment: Same goes for the [#,5]